# Dired: how to do chown as superuser?

Tags: emacs, dired, chown

I'm working on a code I checked from remote repository, where some of it went into that repo having "root" as the file owner. Now I want to move the directory containing the repo to another place, but deleting old files fails under regular user. Also `dired-do-chown` fails because I need to be root to change the file owner.

Is there any way to call dired commands as root? (like tramp for finding files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just type `/sudo:root@localhost/...` when `C-x C-f` asks you for file name. This will open a trampified dired where `dired-do-chown` and other dired commands work just fine.

(Note that you can press `TAB` after `/sudo:`, and minibuffer completion will insert the `@localhost` boilerplate.)